# Stopping MapReduce jobs, RunningJob#killJob vs YarnClient#killApplication

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Before upgrading to MR2 (YARN) I would obtain a reference to a `RunningJob` and invoke [`#killJob`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RunningJob.html#killJob()) in order to force a shutdown on a MapReduce job.

After upgrading to YARN, I see that `YarnClient` provides a [`#killApplication`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html#killApplication(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationId)) method.

Should I bother to switching from the former to the latter? Is there any benefit?

Comment: I assume the latter stops the application master as well as all related mappers and reducers

Comment: This is true, but the former does as well.

Comment: By the way, killJob didn't go away. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#killJob()

Comment: Definitely, it's still there. I'm still using it. I saw the newer API provided its own method for doing the same thing though, and wondered whether it was beneficial to switch.

Comment: Your usage depends on the data you have at the time. Do you have a Job object, or an applicationId?

Comment: As I have it written currently, I obtain the RunningJob reference by a jobId lookup. jobId is the same as applicationId with one string swap, so I could easily do it either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MapReduce runs in YARN mode, then methods of the MapReduce client pass through a wrapper class called `YARNRunner`.  Job kill requests execute through [`YARNRunner#killApplication`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/YARNRunner.java#L612-L618).

```java
private void killApplication(ApplicationId appId) throws IOException {
  try {
    resMgrDelegate.killApplication(appId);
  } catch (YarnException e) {
    throw new IOException(e);
  }
}
```

That goes into a class called [`ResourceMgrDelegate`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ResourceMgrDelegate.java#L84).  This class internally maintains an instance of the `YarnClient`.

```java
protected YarnClient client;
```

Specifically, the call flow delegates into [`ResourceMgrDelegate#killApplication`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ResourceMgrDelegate.java#L293-L297).

```java
@Override
public void killApplication(ApplicationId applicationId)
    throws YarnException, IOException {
  client.killApplication(applicationId);
}
```

Thus, we can conclude that calling `RunningJob#killJob` or calling `YarnClient#killApplication` are effectively the same in your use case.  Both methods would flow into the same code path of the `YarnClient` and ultimately invoke an RPC to the ResourceManager to request killing the YARN application.  There is no compelling reason to change your code, unless you want code that is capable of stopping any arbitrary YARN applications (not just MapReduce).